# .htaccess Rewrite problems

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Either I really need to go back to the school desk, or there is something weird going on.

The following doesn't work, as real physical files and directories do not resolve:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

  # The following rule must not affect real physical files, but does
  RewriteRule ^(img/.*)$ http://old.site.com/$1 [L,R=301]

  RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

However this piece of code works and resolves real files and folders just fine:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

  RewriteRule ^(img/.*)$ http://old.site.com/$1 [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

  RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Do I really need a new RewriteCond preceeding each and every RewriteRule?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RewriteCond is only applicable to the very next RewriteRule. So yes in your case you will need a RewriteCond preceeding each and every RewriteRule.

**But good news is that it can be avoided.**

If you want to avoid writing these multiple RewriteCond you can do so as this code:

```
## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(img/.*)$ http://old.site.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

You can't have two `RewriteRule`s based on one (set of) `RewriteCond`s.

Some quotes from the [manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

`Each rule can have an unlimited number of attached rule conditions...`

`One or more RewriteCond can precede a RewriteRule directive...`

`The RewriteRule directive [...] can occur more than once, with each instance defining a single rewrite rule...`

Comment: *voteup* Thank you very much for your answer. I will accept anubhavas answer since it's provided with a great workaround example. But I'd like to share my gratitude for pointing this out.